# Visual Studio Code: VS Code | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_crypt'

Tags: python

I was making a simple test with python Flask in windows. After the base code:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify

Flask(__name__)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def ping():
        return jsonify({"response": "funcionando"})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=4000, debug=True)
```

I try to run it from terminal:
python app.py

and this error comes across:

```
import _crypt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_crypt'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\src\app.py", line 1, in <module>
    from crypt import methods
```

That package is not supported on windows, therefore it will fail to run the api.

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I discover that VS Code add this line at the top:

```
from crypt import methods
```

Just delete this line (or comment it), save it and run it again.

Now everything will work